# Xamarin Android - Directly Connected to SQL Server - Error Upon Relase Mode

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Hello I am new in xamarin development.

My app is directly connected to the sql server and it is working fine in debug mode.

here is my sample code for testing the connection:

```
public string ConnectTest()
{
    try
    {
        string con = "Data Source=ServerName;" +
            "Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" +
            "User id=UserName;" +
            "Password=Secret;";
        using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            db.Open();
            return "sucess";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string err = ex.ToString();
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            err = err + " " + ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        return err;
    }
}
```

it returns "success" as it should be. However, when i change my project to "release" mode and deploy it to my device it returns this error.

[image]

Troubleshooting Linker (my current linker prop is **None**):

1. Change the linker properties to **Sdk and User Assemblies**
   result : App crashes on start
2. Change the linker properties to **Sdk Assemblies Only**
   result : **Build Failed**

1>  Touching "obj\Release\strip.flag".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1586,5): error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1586,5): error MSB4018: Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationException' (defined in 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') from 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' could not be resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve **System.Configuration.ConfigurationException**
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1586,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)

Comment: Should your app really be directly connected to the database?

Comment: Is this Xamarin.forms running on android or Xamarin.android?

Comment: Xamarin.android sir, yes i need it because i need to finish it as soon as possible (no experience with REST)

Comment: Check your linker settings.

Comment: In which line the exception is thrown and what is the inner exception?

Comment: My linker settings is set to "none" @tequila slammer

Comment: Im not sure because im on release mode, but i think when the program reaches the "SqlConnection" class, i edited sample code and it returns the same error, no inner exception @Patrick